# Что в данном случаи делает getInputStream()?

Tags: java, c#

Помогите разобратья в следующем Java коде

```
InputStream ignored = resource.getInputStream()
```

я с Java не работаю, но у меня есть задача переписать одно приложение с Java на NET, встретил данную строку, правильно ли я понимаю, что `ignored` в данном случаи получит поток данных для записи/чтения из `resource`?

И могли бы Вы подсказать, как правильно будет выглядеть данная конструкция на C#? (если знаете)

Comment: А что такое resource? Можно пожалуйста весь участок кода целиком?
В теории тогда вам нужно сделать File.open()
Либо манипулировать StreamReader/SteamWriter.
Все вышеперечисленные объекты находятся в System.IO.

Comment: Resource в данном случаи это объект, который содержит внутри себя список определенных файлов, грубо говоря массив(наверное его можно так назвать) файлов

Comment: @Nikita. хм. Какой тип у этого объекта. Нельзя понять, что делает метод не посмотрев на него. Судя по названию метода объект ignored является каким-то steam

Comment: Да, вы правы, он является `InputStream`(ом)

Comment: Вот дополнительная часть кода, если Вам это поможет


Resource resource = resources.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
            try (InputStream ignored = resource.getInputStream()) {

Comment: @Nikita, чтобы успешно перевести данный код на net. Необходимо понять что такое resources, перенести его на net (или найти замену) и уже потом переносить ваш код.

Comment: `Resource` - это InputStreamSource (полностью org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource)

Comment: @Nikita, ага, я увидел. В теории тогда вам нужно сделать File.open()

Comment: @Nikita, передайте туда путь к файлу, и в качестве FileMode указывайте как нужно открыть файл (чтение\запись). Также можете воспользоваться SteamWriter/StreamReader

Comment: @Nikita, ах да, всё это находится в System.IO

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314140/12888024

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/648673)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) это интерфейс из библиотеки spring.

Он обобщает понятие файла и позволяет клиентам работать с ресурсами независимо от того, где одни находятся. Это может быть [файл в файловой системе](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html), [файл в classpath](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html), ресурс [доступный по URL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html) или [массив байт в памяти](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ByteArrayResource.html) и еще есть и другие реализации.

Клиенты работают с ресурсом используя метод [getInputStream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamSource.html#getInputStream--) который возвращает `InputStream`, т.е. поток ввода-вывода, который позволяет читать (но не изменять) содержимое ресурса.

В .net прямого аналога `InputStream`, насколько я понимаю, нет. Наиболее близким является [Stream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=net-5.0#definition), но открытый в режиме только для чтения.

Аналогом `Resource` из spring for java является [IResource](https://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/resources.html) из [spring .net](https://springframework.net/):

```
IResource resource = ... ;
Stream stream = resource.InputStream;
```